# How to skip calling function in unit testing controller moq context?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

This is my controller

```
BusinessLayer.Lookup.Lookup_Rooms RoomsBL = new BusinessLayer.Lookup.Lookup_Rooms();

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateRoom(UMIS_Portal_BackEnd.Areas.StudentAcadimic.Models.RoomLocationModel room) {
        
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

           

           
            int? Serial = RoomsBL.Lookup_RoomInsert(room.BuildingFloorID, room.RoomName, room.Min_Capacity, room.Max_Capacity);
           
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            
            ViewBag.Messages = error.InnerException.Message;
         
        }

    }
    return View();
}
```

I only want to test that there is view exist for this action result so i write this code

```
[TestMethod()]
public void CreateRoomTestPost()
{
    LookupRoomsController controller = new LookupRoomsController();
  
    UMIS_Portal_BackEnd.Areas.StudentAcadimic.Models.RoomLocationModel room = new UMIS_Portal_BackEnd.Areas.StudentAcadimic.Models.RoomLocationModel();

    ViewResult viewResult = controller.CreateRoom(room) as ViewResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult);
 
}
```

I want the test to skip calling

```
int? Serial = RoomsBL.Lookup_RoomInsert(room.BuildingFloorID, room.RoomName, room.Min_Capacity, room.Max_Capacity);
```

on the main controller action.

Comment: you can test with invalid data to simulate `modelstate` in error state, also setup the moq to throw exception on `Lookup_RoomInsert`

Comment: The problem is that the controller is tightly coupled to implementation details instead of having abstractions explicitly injected into it. The `Lookup_Rooms ` needs to be abstracted and injected into the controller. That way a mocked one can be made to perform no action when `Lookup_RoomInsert` is invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the controller is tightly coupled to implementation details

```
BusinessLayer.Lookup.Lookup_Rooms RoomsBL = new BusinessLayer.Lookup.Lookup_Rooms();
```

instead of having abstractions explicitly injected into it. It is not the controller's responsibility to create its dependencies. (Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) and Separations of Concerns (Soc))

The `Lookup_Rooms`  needs to be abstracted

```
public interface ILookup_Rooms {
    //...
}

public class Lookup_Rooms : ILookup_Rooms {
    //...
}
```

and the abstraction explicitly injected into the controller.

```
private readonly BusinessLayer.Lookup.ILookup_Rooms RoomsBL;

//CTOR
public LookupRoomsController(ILookup_Rooms RoomsBL) {
    this.RoomsBL = RoomsBL;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateRoom(RoomLocationModel room) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        try {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here    
           
            int? Serial = RoomsBL.Lookup_RoomInsert(room.BuildingFloorID, room.RoomName, room.Min_Capacity, room.Max_Capacity);               
        } catch (Exception error) {
            ViewBag.Messages = error.InnerException.Message;             
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

That way a mocked one can be made to perform no action when `Lookup_RoomInsert` is invoked in an isolated unit test.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void CreateRoomTestPost() {
    // Arrange
    ILookup_Rooms mock = Mock.Of<ILookup_Rooms>(); //using MOQ

    LookupRoomsController controller = new LookupRoomsController(mock);
  
    RoomLocationModel room = new RoomLocationModel();

    // Act
    ViewResult viewResult = controller.CreateRoom(room) as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(viewResult);
}
```

Finally, the abstraction and implementation should be registered with a DI container so that the actual implementation can be properly injected into the controller when the system is running in production.